# Sorting df by column name of type timestamp

Tags: pandas, sorting, python-datetime

I have a dataframe df which consists of columns of countries and rows of dates.  The index is of type "DateTime."
I would like to sort the df by the values of each country by the last element in the series (eg, the latest date) and the graph the "top N" countries by this latest value.
I thought if I sorted the transpose of the df and then slice it, I would have what I need.  Hence, if N = 10, then I would  select df[0:9].
However,when I attempt to select the last column, I get a 'keyerror' message, referencing the selected column:

KeyError: '2021-03-28 00:00:00'.

I'm stumped....

```
df_T = df.transpose()
column_name = str(df_T.columns[-1])
df_T.sort_values(by = column_name, axis = 'columns', inplace = True)
#select the top 10 countries by latest value, eg
# plot df_T[0:9]
```

**What I'm trying to do, example df:**

```
                A    B     C     ....  X    Y    Z
2021-03-29     10    20    5     ....  50  100   7
2021-03-28      9    19    4     ....  45   90   6
2021-03-27      8    15    2     ....  40   80   4
...
2021-01-03      0     0    0     ....   0    0   0
```

I want to select series representing by the greatest N values as of the latest index value (eg, latest date).

Comment: Can you share first 3-4 rows of data?

Comment: The transposed data or the original df?

Comment: original is best.

Comment: There are about 200 columns...how would you like it?

Comment: OK, then rather transpose ;)

Comment: Done - pasted above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230539/discussion-between-gpb-and-jezrael).

Comment: Check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: This question in of it self is fine but due to the lack of [mcve] I'm voting to close. Will happily remove if you meet the standard guidelines of [ask]

Comment: It's a complex example and jezrael is helping me articulate better.   Thank you